# Python adding lists

Tags: python-3.5

I am importing data from a file, which is working correctly. I have appended the data from this file into 3 different lists, name, mark, mark2 although I don't understand how or if i can make a new list called total_marks and add a calculation appending mark + mark2 into total_marks. Tried looking about for help on this and couldn't find much relating to it. The plan is to actually add the two lists together and work out a percentage which the total marks would be 150.

Comment: Please show the code that you have that is relevant to the question you are asking.

Comment: Show an example input and example output. Also: I highly recommend that once you've gotten past learning the basics that you then take the time to learn two libraries: pandas and xlwings. These will greatly help your ability to interact between python and excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the two lists item by item:

```
combined = []
for m1, m2 in zip(mark, mark2): 
    combined.append(m1+m2)
```

The zip function returns an item pair from the two lists for each pair in the lists.:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip

Then you can perform the final operation this way:

```
final = []
for m in combined: 
    final.append(m/150*100)
```

As I said in my comment, I highly recommend that once you've gotten past learning the basics that you then take the time to learn two libraries: pandas and xlwings. These will greatly help your ability to interact between python and excel. An operation like you have here becomes much simpler once you learn pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way, using pandas.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('Classmarks.csv', index_col = 'student_name', names = ('student_name', 'mark1', 'mark2'), header = None)

df['combined'] = df['mark1'] + df['mark2']
df['final'] = df['combined'] / 150 * 100

print(df)
```

Don't have to do any loops using pandas. And you can then write it back to a csv file:

```
df.to_csv('Classmarksout.csv')
```

Comment: Says 'no module named pandas'

Comment: Need to install it. `pip install pandas` from the command line should do it.